# Discord BOT not logging in (anymore)

Tags: node.js

i made a Discord bot which was working just fine until recently; since yesterday it's refusing to log in (output says invalid token was provided but creating a new token and putting it into code won't work).

The funny part is I actually have two versions of the same bot (deploy and test where the latter is only in one of my servers where i test new functions before implementing them in the deployed version).

Just replacing the token with the "test-bot" one fix the issue and allows me to correctly login (with the wrong bot of course since I'm using bot-test token).

To verify the token i made this very small script:

```
 client.login(botToken).then().catch(reason => {

    console.log("Login failed: " + reason);
    console.log("Token used: " + botToken);

}); //login in discord
```

This allows me, in case of failed login to have similiar output:

Login failed: Error [TOKEN_INVALID]: An invalid token was provided.
Token used: NjAxMzc3Mzg3NDgwODc1MDE4.Xr5Cyg.xhX3QYqk0prPC7y3KS0yc5JA02U

[Here you can see a screenshot from discord bot page where you can double-check the token used IS correct (the token now has been reset so this one won't be valid anymore)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cmc9z.png)

I can tell the import method of the token (it's imported from another file) works fine (bot.js can see it and what i actually do when I change version is commenting/decommenting 2 lines of code (containing token and client ID which is used by a bot function).

Additional info:

I'm using Discord 12 at the moment but the bug started yesterday giving out the same result and I had installed discord 11+ back then.

nodejs version used is 12.16.3
npm version used is 6.14.4
bot is hosted in a VPS running Debian 9

Is anyone able to help with this or encountered similiar error?

Thanks in advance,